# How to configure ArcGIS Server wms to show images in a popup?

Tags: wms, arcgis-online

I am using ArcGIS Online to host an online webapp showing a point layer. The point layer comes from an ArcGIS for Server 10.3.1 wms layer. In the attribute table is a field which has a URL pointing to an image which is accessable over the internet. At the moment arcgis online can show the attribute table of the wms including the path to the image as text. I obviously want the pop-up to show the image and not the path.

Is this possible with a wms layer through ArcGIS Online? I don´t seem to be able to configure the popups for wms layers.